# aws CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND console web codepipeline with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to complete a codepipeline with the cloudformation service and this error is generated. It must be said that the separate cloudformation service works well. The complete error is:

> JobFailed
>   Requires capabilities: [CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND] (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InsufficientCapabilitiesException; Request ID: 1a977102-f829-11e8-b5c6-f7cc8454c4d0)

The solutions I have is to add the `CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND --capabilities` parameter but that only applies to CLI and my case is by web console.

Comment: To expand on PJR's answer, since I'v seen others struggle with the formatting for this in other threads, the line from the .json file should read like this if you need to specify multiple capabilities: "Capabilities": "CAPABILITY_IAM,CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND",

Comment: Thanks @PeteFranzen!!! Major help.

Answer (score 5):

Ran into the same problem, I could not find a way to do it through the console.
However it works well with the CLI and you can find detailed documentation on pipeline update here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codepipeline/update-pipeline.html

The way I did it was :

1. make a get-pipeline to get the current pipeline structure
2. save the result as a json file
3. from the json file : remove the metadata section, add a capabilities attribute with your value in configuration section
4. use the update-pipeline command with --cli-input-json option specifying the previous json file

Comment: this just worked for me... the relevant line in the json ended up like ```"Capabilities": "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM,CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND"```.  Note the lack of a space between the capabilities, that was essential

Answer (score 2):

Sample [Note the changes marked with arrows]:

```
    {
    "pipeline": {
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789234:role/service-role/AWSCodePipelineServiceRole-us-east-1-SAMpipeline", 
        "stages": [
            {
                "name": "Source", 
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "inputArtifacts": [], 
                        "name": "Source", 
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Source", 
                            "owner": "AWS", 
                            "version": "1", 
                            "provider": "CodeCommit"
                        }, 
                        "outputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "SourceArtifact"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "configuration": {
                            "PollForSourceChanges": "false", 
                            "BranchName": "master", 
                            "RepositoryName": "CFNrepo"
                        }, 
                        "runOrder": 1
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Build", 
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "SourceArtifact"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "name": "Build", 
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Build", 
                            "owner": "AWS", 
                            "version": "1", 
                            "provider": "CodeBuild"
                        }, 
                        "outputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "BuildArtifact"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "configuration": {
                            "ProjectName": "SAMproject"
                        }, 
                        "runOrder": 1
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Deploy", 
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "BuildArtifact"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "name": "DeployStack", 
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Deploy", 
                            "owner": "AWS", 
                            "version": "1", 
                            "provider": "CloudFormation"
                        }, 
                        "outputArtifacts": [], 
                        "configuration": {
                            "StackName": "s5765722591-cp", 
                            "ActionMode": "CREATE_UPDATE", 
                            "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::298320596430:role/CloudFormationFullAccess", 
                            "Capabilities": "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM,CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND",   <--------------
                            "TemplatePath": "BuildArtifact::template.yaml"
                        }, 
                        "runOrder": 1
                    }, 
                    {
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "BuildArtifact"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "name": "DeployStack2", 
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Deploy", 
                            "owner": "AWS", 
                            "version": "1", 
                            "provider": "CloudFormation"
                        }, 
                        "outputArtifacts": [], 
                        "configuration": {
                            "StackName": "s5765722591-cp2", 
                            "ActionMode": "CREATE_UPDATE", 
                            "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789234:role/CloudFormationFullAccess", 
                            "Capabilities": "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM,CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND",    <-----------
                            "TemplatePath": "BuildArtifact::template.yaml"
                        }, 
                        "runOrder": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ], 
        "artifactStore": {
            "type": "S3", 
            "location": "codepipeline-us-east-1-123456789234"
        }, 
        "name": "SAMpipeline", 
        "version": 5
    }
 }
```